# UITextView text color change issue

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicolor

I am new to iOS development. Now I am working on making a `UITextView` Clickable. Now I can Click on the `UITextView`. I need to change the text to red if it is selected and if not selected to black.

Now my code is working(It will comes to the function each and every time when we tap on the `UITextView` for change color) but the text color is not changing(Sometimes it changes sometimes it not) Here is my code,

```
//Code to make it clickable
UIGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
[Q1TextView addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture1];

//Function to handleTap
- (void) handleTapGesture: (UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{
    switch (recognizer.view.tag) {
        case 1:
            if (tv.textColor == [UIColor redColor]) {
                  NSLog(@"Red -> Black");
                  [Q1TextView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            }
            else{
                 NSLog(@"Black -> Red");
                 [Q1TextView setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            }
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

My Log is like this,

```
Black -> Red
Red -> Black
Black -> Red
Red -> Black
Black -> Red
Red -> Black
```

Comment: There is a bug in iOS: changing text will change color also. You need to change the text color **after** changing the text, i.e. tv.text = @"asd"; tv.textColor = [UIColor whatever].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why implement a tap gesture when you can work o `UITextView` delegate methods.

In your .m file write these down

```
@interface myClass ()<UITextViewDelegate>


-(void)viewDidLoad{
  myTextview.delegate = self;
}
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
textView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switch case use `tag` property of `UITextView`

In `viewDidLoad()` set `Q1TextView.tag = 100`

```
- (void) handleTapGesture: (UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{
    if (recognizer.view == Q1TextView) {

        if (Q1TextView.tag == 100) {
            Q1TextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            Q1TextView.tag = 200;
        }
        else if (Q1TextView.tag == 200){
            Q1TextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            Q1TextView.tag = 100;
        }
    }
 [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: My code is working, My login printing correctly But the font color is not applying, I am using Q1TextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; to change the text color

Comment: I tested my answer, and font color is also changing

Comment: Text color not changing when the text is single line text. I have added some more text to make it 2 lines then my code is working correctly.

Comment: In the property I had set tag for the  Q1TextView (in .xib file).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    if ([[touch.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        //Set Red color
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    if ([[touch.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        //Set Black color
    }
}
```